# How to make Rest API more scalable using spring mvc on increasing number of requests at same time?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, scalability

I have used spring mvc framework for implementing rest api using annotations like @RestController and @RequestMapping etc.

Does `tomcat` container can handle multiple requests on its own by dynamically increasing heap size of `jvm` of hosted server or does application developers needs to handle it . What should be the ideal way of handling multiple request of same get rest api like this .

**Here is sample method signature :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/domain.com/{sourceID}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<?> getCategory(@PathVariable("sourceID") final String sourceID) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Spring handles multiple requests just fine on multiple threads. Make your application requests stateless (so that you can restart the server between requests with no problem), and then if you need to you can just run multiple copies (because you need more memory, CPU, or whatever).

Comment: What makes you think it is not scalable already? This looks like an XY Problem.

Comment: If you can't give proper solution please don't vote down my question

Answer (score 0):

> Does tomcat container can handle multiple requests on its own by dynamically increasing heap size of jvm of hosted server or does application developers needs to handle it .

Tomcat container can easily handle multiple requests but not by increasing the heap size dynamically.

Literally the heap size cannot be changed once a jvm started. Heap size of tomcat can be set using `-Xmn`, `-Xmx` and `-XX:PermSize` if required to change it.

> What should be the ideal way of handling multiple request of same get rest api like this.

This is a broader question and depends upon the project requirement. For general purpose application you can just run it as it is (leave the tomcat configuration as default).

Comment: Will tomcat container create separate response object for different request s right ?

Comment: Absolutely, every request has a different response object.

Comment: The heap size changes all the time.

Comment: I am talking about max heap size which has been allocated to the tomcat.